# Why Won't This StreamBuilder Display Data without Restarting the App?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, stream-builder

I'm trying to get a Flutter project to display a simple list of items returned from the Firebase Realtime Database. The code mostly works, but I have to restart the app each time I log out and log back in as a different user, which isn't what I'm looking for. I need the user's data to appear when they log in. I don't quite understand what all is happening here (I stumbled across a functional solution after several days of trial and error and googling), but I thought a Stream was more or less a 'live' stream of data from a particular source.

EDIT: kPAYEES_NODE is a constant stored elsewhere that resolves to 'users/uid/payees' in the RTDB:

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'auth_service.dart';

final DatabaseReference kUSER_NODE =
    FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('users/${AuthService.getUid()}');
final DatabaseReference kPAYEES_NODE = kUSER_NODE.child('payees');
```

Here's the code in question:

```
class DashboardPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const DashboardPage({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(...),

      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: kPAYEES_NODE.onValue,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          final payees = <Payee>[];
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(child: Column(children: const [Text('No Data')]));
          } else {
            final payeeData =
                (snapshot.data!).snapshot.value as Map<Object?, dynamic>;
            payeeData.forEach((key, value) {
              final dataLast = Map<String, dynamic>.from(value);
              final payee = Payee(
                id: dataLast['id'],
                name: dataLast['name'],
                note: dataLast['note'],
              );
              payees.add(payee);
            });
            return ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: payees.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(
                      payees[index].name,
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(
                      payees[index].id,
                      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  );
                });
          }
        },
      ),

      floatingActionButton: (...),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you include more about ` kPAYEES_NODE.onValue,`

Comment: @YeasinSheikh see edit above. To be clear: the stream IS getting the correct data; when I log out and log back in as a different user, I get the correct user's data (but only after a restart). If I then log out and log in as another user, I get THAT user's correct data (but only after a restart).

Comment: Where is `payees` list defined? my guess is you are receiving the data, but something has gone wrong while displaying it. Can you verify it by printing the snapshot

Answer (score 0):

That's because you only get the UID of the current once in your code, here:

```
FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('users/${AuthService.getUid()}')
```

And by the time this line runs, the `AuthService.getUid()` has a single value. Instead, the code needs to be reevaluated any time a users signs in or out of the app.

In an app where the user can sign in and out, the UID values are a stream like the one exposed by `FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()` as shown in the Firebase documentation on [getting the current user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/manage-users#get_a_users_profile). You can wrap the stream that is returned by `authStateChanges()` in a `StreamBuilder`, and then create the database reference **inside** of that builder, to have it respond to changes in the authentication state.

Comment: Maybe I'm close, then. My MaterialApp's home: property calls an AuthState class. That class has a 'getUID()' function (used by various other classes), and it's body is a StreamBuilder whose stream is 'FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges()'. If the snapshot has data, the app shows the dashboard page (where my list isn't showing up without a reload), and if not it shows the login page.

Do I just have this code in the wrong place?

Comment: It's hard to say much based on a description of the code. I recommend simplifying the code to all be in a single class  and then show that or post a new question with it.  --- What I *can* say based on the code you shared is that `final DatabaseReference kUSER_NODE = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('users/${AuthService.getUid()}');` is likely only evaluated once, and it needs to be evaluated whenever the active UID changes, hence needing a stream builder.

Comment: I've condensed the code as much as possible and posted a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74158494/why-wont-this-streambuilder-display-data-without-restarting-the-app-revised-c).