# Why Won't This StreamBuilder Display Data without Restarting the App - Revised Code for Review

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database, stream-builder

CURRENT BEHAVIOR: When I log out of my app and then log back in as a different user, I am taken to a dashboard page with no data. I have to restart the app from the IDE in order to load the user's data.

DESIRED BEHAVIOR: When I log in as a given user, the dashboard page should show that user's data without having to reload/restart/refresh anything.

Based on feedback in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74145220/why-wont-this-streambuilder-display-data-without-restarting-the-app/74152506?noredirect=1#comment130925289_74152506), I've condensed my code as much as possible while trying not to remove anything that might help identify my issue. Apologies for the ugliness of the code - I removed as much white space and formatting as I could in order to shorten the paste.

I am working on an app that uses the Firebase Realtime Database as a back-end. The app is user-based, so each user will have a directory, with several subdirectories within each user directory. I'm trying to display a simple list of items returned from the database. Currently I have to restart the app each time I log out and log back in as a different user, which isn't what I'm looking for. I need a given user's data to appear upon login. I don't quite understand what all is happening here (I stumbled across a functional solution after several days of trial and error and googling), but I thought a Stream was more or less a 'live' stream of data from a particular source.

The code snippet below is actually taken from three or four different files in my project; I've put everything in one file and stripped out formatting and white space to make it more compact. I don't think I removed anything material to my problem.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform);
  runApp(const FlipBooks());}

class FlipBooks extends StatelessWidget {const FlipBooks({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => const MaterialApp(home: AuthService());}

class AuthService extends StatelessWidget {const AuthService({super.key});
  static String getUid() => FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder<User?>(
        stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {return const DashboardPage();
            } else {return const LoginPage();}}))}}

class DashboardPage extends StatelessWidget {const DashboardPage({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          child: GestureDetector(onTap: () {FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();},
              child: const Icon(Icons.logout))]),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        // kPAYEES_NODE is defined in constants.dart as
        // kUSER_NODE.child('payees')
        // kUSER_NODE is defined as FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('users/${AuthService.getUid()}')
        stream: kPAYEES_NODE.onValue,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          final payees = <Payee>[];
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {return Center(child: Column(children: const [Text('No Data')]));
          } else {
              final payeeData = (snapshot.data!).snapshot.value as Map<Object?, dynamic>;
              payeeData.forEach((key, value) {
                final dataLast = Map<String, dynamic>.from(value);
                final payee = Payee(id: dataLast['id'], name: dataLast['name'], note: dataLast['note']);
              payees.add(payee);});
            return ListView.builder(
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemCount: payees.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(title: Text(payees[index].name), subtitle: Text(payees[index].id));});}}),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => AddThing(), fullscreenDialog: true));},
        child: const Icon(Icons.add));}}

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {const LoginPage({super.key});
  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  // variables for FocusNodes, TextEditingControllers, FormKey

  Future signIn() async {
    try {await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {context.showErrorSnackBar(message: e.toString());}}

  Future signUp() async {
    try {await FirebaseAuth.instance.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {context.showErrorSnackBar(message: e.toString());}}

  Future sendEm() async {
    var methods = await FirebaseAuth.instance.fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email);
    if (methods.contains('password')) {return signIn();
    } else {showDialog(...); // give user option to register or try again
    return;}}

  Future passwordReset() async {
    try {await FirebaseAuth.instance.sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
      showDialog(...); // show reset email sent dialog
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {context.showErrorSnackBar(message: e.toString());}}

  @override
  void dispose() {...}

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            Expanded(...), // logo, welcome text
              Form(...), // email+pw fields, forgot pw link => passwordReset(), submit button => sendEm()
            ]))));}}
```

Comment: Can you post a minimum example to reproduce it or the complete which can be executed locally? I don't think there is any problem in the current code

Answer (score 0):

As I said in [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74145220/why-wont-this-streambuilder-display-data-without-restarting-the-app/74152506?noredirect=1#comment130932115_74152506), you're defining `static String getUid() => FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;` which means that is only evaluates the current user once. Since the user can sign in and out, the UID is a stream and that requires that you use `authStateChanges` to expose it to your `DashboardPage`, just as you already do in the `AuthService` itself.

```
class AuthService extends StatelessWidget {const AuthService({super.key});
  static Stream<String?> getUid() => FirebaseAuth.instance. authStateChanges().map<String?>((user) => user?.uid);
  ...
}
```

*I didn't run the above code, so there might be some typos or minor errors in it.*

Now you can use a `StreamBuilder` when you call `getUid()` and get a stream of `UID` values (or `null` when no one is signed in).

Comment: Implementing the code above causes the app not to load any data at all, even after restart / reload. I either don't understand your answer, or I don't understand the actual question I need an answer to. Either way, I appreciate you taking the time to try and help.